# How to get all available languages from Localized Fields in pimcore?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-locale, pimcore

I'm a little bit stuck with this: I have a controller where I'm collecting all available languages for an object in pimcore.
Right now I simply take a Localized Field from that object, run through it via `foreach` and fill an array with the Localized Fields's keys. So I get all languages for that object. But this is the most ugly piece I've ever coded :)

Update - here is the code:

```
$o = Object_Product::getById(SOME_ID);
$availableLanguages = array();
// 'category' is an attribute of my product-object that uses Localized Fields
foreach ($o->getCategory()->getLocalizedfields()->getItems() as $language => $value) {
    $availableLanguages[] = $language;
}
```

So I get an array that looks like:

```
$availableLanguages(
    0 => 'en',
    1 => 'de',
    2 => 'it'
    // etc.
);
```

I'm afraid I've thought too much about it and now I'm missing the forest for the trees - there must be an (more) elegant way for this. Basically Zend_Locale should have this info too, but I don't get it.

Does anyone have a clue for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your current *ugly* code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting all available languages (enabled translations) in Pimcore:
Starting from Pimcore 6.9 and in currently available Pimcore 10 we use:

```
$languages = \Pimcore\Tool::getValidLanguages();
```

The documentation is here https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Localized_Fields.html

As I see in the original question, the author is creating some export for DataObject with all available translations.
In such case we need to disable Fallback languages:

```
\Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Localizedfield::setGetFallbackValues(false);
```

This will allow us to get an empty value for fieds without translation instead of default language value.

Answer (score 2):

After crawling through tons of pimcore-backend-Classes I found the solution [here](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/lib/Pimcore/Tool.php#L70):

```
$config = \Zend_Registry::get("pimcore_config_system");
$validLanguages = strval($config->general->validLanguages);
```

Comment: Just a minor addition - a better way to retrieve the Zend_Config configuration object is:

`$config = Pimcore_Config::getSystemConfig();
var_dump($config->general->validLanguages);
// result: string(5) "en,de"`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, thats the bulletproofer way.

Comment: Or you could use `Pimcore_Tool::getValidLanguages();`

Comment: In Pimcore 6.9:
` \Pimcore\Tool::getValidLanguages()`